# Calculate factor difference between two list items

Tags: python

I have the following question, for which I can't seem to find an answer.
My python knowledge is basic and i'm working with version 2.7.2 and 2.6.5 right now.

Let's say I have the following list:

```
list1 = [1642842,780497,1506284,1438592,1266530,1154853,965861,610252,1091847,1209404,1128111,749998]
```

I want to know the factor difference for each 2 items (item 0,1 item 1,2 item 2,3 etc).

The output should be like this (but preferable rounded up to 1 decimal):

```
list2 = [2.1048665145,0.5181605859,1.047054342,1.1358530789,1.0967023509,1.195672048, 1.5827248415,0.5589171377,0.9027975763,1.0720611713,1.5041520111]
```

The final result I'm looking for is that when the factor is more than 1.5, I want to report the 2 list items numbers and their factor value.

item 0,1
value 2.1

item 6,7
value 1.6

item 10,11
value 1.5

How should I do this?

Finding the numeric difference can be easily done with:

```
print numpy.diff(list1)
```

or

```
for i in (abs(x - y) for (x, y) in zip(list1[1:], list1[:-1])):
    print i
```

But i'm breaking my head to find a sollution for my question above?
I tried a few things with the above code, but I can't seem to get a good result.

Also note that although I will filter the data in list1 first, it will contain upfollowing zero values which gave me dividebyzero problems before.

EDIT: Thanks for the solutions, most of them do exactly what I want. Unfortunately the items in these lists have a fixed position. This information, I can't discard, so filtering some of the items out of the list to prevent errors like 'ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero' is not really an option. To explain a bit more, there are likely to be lists of the following format:

```
list1 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,5,65,456,456456,456564,456666,666666,2344,233,232,122,88,6,0,0,0,0]
```

What is a pythonic way with any of the solutions below to address this issue?
To be a bit more specific about the output:

item 0,1 value 0

item 1,2 value 0

item 2,3 value 0

etc.

item 8,9 value 2.5

item 9,10 value 13

etc.

Last edit: I'll filter the data anyway instead of creating problems to fix.
Thanks for the answers all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way:

```
list1 = [1642842,780497,1506284,1438592,1266530,1154853,965861,610252,1091847,1209404,1128111,749998]
list2 = [(i, a, b, (1.0*a)/b) for (i, (a, b)) in enumerate(zip(list1, list1[1:]))]
for i, a, b, f in filter(lambda (i, a, b, f): f > 1.5, list2):
    print 'item {0} ({1}), {2} ({3}) value {4:.1f}'.format(i, a, i+1, b, f)
```

Output:

```
item 0 (1642842), 1 (780497) value 2.1
item 6 (965861), 7 (610252) value 1.6
item 10 (1128111), 11 (749998) value 1.5
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the `pairwise` function from the itertools [recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
import itertools

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return itertools.izip(a, b)

diff = [round(abs(x/float(y)), 1) for x, y in pairwise(your_iterable)]
```

Comment: thanks for mention it, but isn't this a little bit overkill for the task?

Comment: I find this solution to be particularly readable, and `pairwise` is quite a general function that may have uses elsewhere. One can see immediately what this does and how it works. I can't say the same for the other answers. This answer will also work with iterables without the list overhead (if you replace the last list comprehension with a generator).

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> g = ((i, i + 1, round(1.0 * list1[i] / list1[i + 1], 2)) for i in range(len(list1) - 1))
>>> print [x for x in g if x[2] >= 1.5]
[(0, 1, 2.1), (6, 7, 1.58), (10, 11, 1.5)]
```

or

```
>>> g1 = ((i, i + 1) for i in range(len(list1) - 1))
>>> g2 = ((x, y, round(float(list1[x]) / list1[y], 2)) for x, y in g1)
>>> print [x for x in g2 if x[2] >= 1.5]
[(0, 1, 2.1), (6, 7, 1.58), (10, 11, 1.5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this solution also:

```py
a = [..., ..., ]

for i,v in enumerate(map(lambda t: float(t[0])/float(t[1]), zip(a, a[1:]))):
    print "{0},{1} - {2:.1f}".format(i,i+1,v)
```

Test:

```
>>> a
[24144, 24666, 10421, 28925, 23619, 13703, 20766, 10029, 23655, 22183]
>>> for i,v in enumerate(map(lambda t: float(t[0])/float(t[1]), zip(a, a[1:]))):
...     print "{0},{1} - {2:.1f}".format(i,i+1,v)
...
0,1 - 1.0
1,2 - 2.4
2,3 - 0.4
3,4 - 1.2
4,5 - 1.7
5,6 - 0.7
6,7 - 2.1
7,8 - 0.4
8,9 - 1.1
>>>
```

Comment: Cast: `enumerate` is used to access index in for-loop, `map` is used to perform function over list, `lambda` is used to define function, `zip` is used to form array pairs from initial list

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
  for i in (float(x)/y if x > y else float(y)/x for (x, y) in zip(list1[1:], list1[:-1])):
      print i
```